# MVC MusicStore Artist.Name Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Cracking my head while learning MVC through MVC MusicStore  . Got this error for Model.Artist.Name for Details View page .

My Storecontroller Details method should be fine .

```
    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        //returns and albums searched from the id 
        var albums = storeDB.Albums.Find(id);
        return View(albums);
    }
```

And this is how I output the view

```
    <li>Price : <%=Model.Price %></li>
    <li>Artist : <%=Model.Artist.Name%></li>
```

Works fine for the price , and it only show error for Model.Genre.Name and Artist.Name . I am suspecting the declaration for these properties in sampledata.cs caused this issue

```
    Artist = artists.Single(a => a.Name == "Aaron Copland & London Symphony Orchestra")
```

But my knowledge of this is too weak to make up anything .  Please help .

Alright , the value is fetched from a class file looking like this

```
    protected override void Seed(MusicStoreEntities context)
    {
        var artists = new List<Artist>
        {
            new Artist { Name = "Aaron Copland & London Symphony Orchestra" },
            etcetc
        }
         new List<Album>
        {
            new Album { Title = "ABC", Artist= artists.Single(g => g.Name == "Test")}
        }
    }
```

Take notice on how the value are being assigned , I can access Model.Title fine (where Model as the short hand) , but Model.Artist.Name caused me that error  .

**Solved**

Alright , got it to work by adding **virtual keyword** to the Artist and Genre declaration in Album class . But I am still not sure what happens and would like to have anyone care to shed some lights .

In my Album class , before it is solved it looks like this

```
public class Album
{
    public int AlbumId { get; set; }
    public int GenreId { get; set; }
    public int ArtistId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string AlbumArtUrl { get; set; }

    public Genre Genre { get; set; }
    public Artist Artist { get; set; }
}
```

The error caused by Genre and Artist is solved by adding Virtual keyword

```
    public virtual Artist Artist { get; set; }
```

Somehow , I still couldn't justify what happens and wish to learn more . Anyone care to explain ?

It goes like this , Album.cs

```
namespace MvcMusicStore.Models
{
    public class Album
    {
        public int AlbumId { get; set; }
        public int GenreId { get; set; }
        public int ArtistId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }
        public virtual Artist Artist { get; set; }
    }
}
```

using EF MusicStore.cs

```
namespace MvcMusicStore.Models
{
    //represent entity framework , handle create ,read , update and del ops 
    public class MusicStoreEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Artist> Artists { get; set; }

    }
}
```

and implemented in StoreController.cs

```
    MusicStoreEntities storeDB = new MusicStoreEntities();

    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        //returns and albums searched from the id 
        var albums = storeDB.Albums.Find(id);
        return View(albums);
    }
```

Finally the sample data

```
protected override void Seed(MusicStoreEntities context)
{
    var artists = new List<Artist>
    {
        new Artist { Name = "Aaron Copland & London Symphony Orchestra" },
        etcetc
    }
     new List<Album>
    {
        new Album { Title = "ABC", Artist= artists.Single(g => g.Name == "Test")}
    }
}
```

Comment: debug - stop on the return View(albums) statement. What does albums look like? Does it have values for Artist and Genre?

Comment: Yes there is , the values are fetched from a class , which suppose to represent a database .

Comment: You need to post more code - there is nothing wrong with what you have posted, and if albums.Artist.Name is popupated when you debug, then you should not get the error you report.  What does Albums class look like? What about Album?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright , got it to work by adding virtual keyword to the Artist and Genre declaration in Album class . But I am still not sure what happens and would like to have anyone care to shed some lights .

See above .

Comment: You are lazy-loading the Artist and Genre, which involves another trip back to the SQL Server, so you are actually making 3 requests here. virtual is needed to allow the ORM to hook into the properties and lazy load them, it creates dynamic proxies of those properties.

Answer (score 3):

You are right. The error is referring to the fact that the Genre object and the Artist object has not been instantiated, and so attempting to access the Name property of either is throwing the error.

The issue is happening within the Find() method. If you are using LinqToSql, EF, NHibernate or simliar, check that your mapping is correct.

**Update:**

Based on the revised code, if you are doing a `artists.Single(g => g.Name == "Test")` then this will would throw a `NullReferenceException` if there is no Artist with the name "Test" or whatever.

I would advise doing the match on something other than a string. Use an Id to perform the match if possible. This will provide a much more reliable match condition.

Ideally you should use `SingleOrDefault()` and check whether `null` is returned.

Answer (score 2):

It looks that `Artist` or `Name` is `null`.

That is to say the property `Artist` of `Model` does not have a reference to an initialised instance of an `Artist`, or a likewise scenario for `Name` of an `Artist` instance. You should always check for `null` values prior to attempting to access an object:

```
if (Model.Artist != null)
{
    //do something with artist
}
```

The same explanation would stand for other properties, such as `Genre`, too.

Curiously, though, is that the use of `Single` to get only an individual entity ought to throw an exception if no `Artist` satisfies the query (or more than one of such satisfies) - is this your exact code, or a test that the `Artist` you want does actually exist?

Comment: If the Name property was null, it would not cause this error. Accessing the Name property on an instantiated object, or trying to manipulate a null Name would cause this error.

Comment: @Digbyswift: `<li>Artist : <%=Model.Artist.Name%></li>` <-- that looks like it's trying to access `Name` to me. I'm not entirely sure whether ASP.NET in-line scripting will take issue with a `null` value in this case, but it's a possibility (it may even call `ToString` on such objects by default.)

Comment: I got that piece of code where it uses Single from a mockup class file that suppose to represent a database . 

Where there is a declaration of list for var artists = new List<Artist> {} and then new List<Album> {Title = "A Copland Celebration, Vol. I", Artist = artists.Single(a => a.Name == "Aaron Copland & London Symphony Orchestra") }

There , I can access the title just fine if its assigned to string directly .

Comment: Disappointment: But that wouldn't cause a NullReference exception. It just would not display anything on the page.

Comment: Check my question again , I've submitted a piece of codes for the model class .

Answer (score 0):

GenreId,ArtistId and AlbumId cannot be null
example:

```
public int? GenreId { get; set; }
```