# Difficulty using "public virtual" variables in database creation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, database-design, virtual

I am creating two tables in Visual Web Developer 2010 Express using the following code:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qd7hu.jpg (sorry, the forum will not let me, due to a new account, post pictures directly)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace BarApp.Models
{
    public class Drinks
    {
        public int DrinksId { get; set; }
        public int EstablishmentsID { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public decimal price { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string image { get; set; }

        public virtual Establishments establishment { get; set; }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace BarApp.Models
{
    public class Promotions
    {
        public int PromotionsId { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public float discount { get; set; }
        public int EstablishmentId { get; set; }
        public int DrinkId { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }

        public virtual Establishments establishment { get; set; }
        public virtual Drinks drink { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But when I look at the created tables, the Promotions table has actual rows for the public virtual code, whereas the Drinks table does not.

I am able to have the Drinks table function the way I want elsewhere in the project, but I cannot get Promotions to behave the same way because it appears that "public virtual" is giving different results in each table.

### I do not understand why my Promotions table is actually creating rows for the public virtual variables. Can someone help me understand?

Comment: Upon further reading I have learned that 'virtual' has something to do with the following:

"You are lazy-loading the Artist and Genre, which involves another trip back to the SQL Server, so you are actually making 3 requests here. virtual is needed to allow the ORM to hook into the properties and lazy load them, it creates dynamic proxies of those properties. – Chris Sainty"

- as noted on a question elsewhere. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410081/mvc-musicstore-artist-name-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object)

Comment: I still have not quite solved the problem I am having as I do not quite understand what is happening.  I feel I need to look more into the ORM that the MVC Music Store tutorial (the tutorial that is referenced in the linked question) is referencing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular situation I was not using the conventional way of referencing the Id field of another table.

I simply needed to change the following:

public int EstablishmentId { get; set; }
public int DrinkId { get; set; }

to the following:

public int EstablishmentsId { get; set; }
public int DrinksId { get; set; }

My tables were created as expected after I made this change.